# what is pure translation and pure simulation in programming?

Tags: translation, simulation, programming-languages, implementation

I recently read in the book "programming languages design and implementation by Pratt" that pure translation is seldom used except in cases where the input language is in fact quite similar to the machine language and pure simulation is used in the case of operating system control languages.

I wonder what is the meaning of pure translation and pure simulation in this context?